# why <p> after floating <ul> starts from a new line?

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS and learned a case from W3Schools(http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_float5). In this case, the `<ul>` element is floating, <strike>the `<p>` element next should surround it as I thought, but it starts from a new line instead. Why `<p>` doesn't surround floating `<ul>`? And,</strike> when I remove  `li{display:inline;}` , it seemed no different shown in FireFox and Chrome. Can you explain this for me? Thanks.

Comment: w3schools is not a good learning source by any means.

Comment: @SalmanA It is, however, a good reference imo. Especially for xsl/xpath I don't know any better.

Comment: Nevermind. Clicked w3fools, no further questions.

Answer (score 2):

Why shouldn't it? A `<p>` by definition starts a new paragraph, which implies a new line. You're asking "why is the door shut after I close it?"

Comment: By definition yes, but with a floating element above it, it should move up, pretending that the floated element isn't there (see http://jsfiddle.net/zmncP/).

Answer (score 0):

Trying giving your p tag...

```
display:block; //maybe unnecessary
overflow:auto; //very important for containing floats
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called nesting. Whatever is inside the `<p>` tag will be...well...inside it. if you write it like:

```
    <p>
    <ul>
    //content
    </ul>
    </p>
```

Then your `<ul>` will be in the paragraph tag. and like marc said, paragraphs always start a new line by definition.